# AngularJS Directives - linking attribute value to scope property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm using angular-nvd3 for charting in my application. I created a custom directives to pass the options from the directive instead of setting them in the controller.

View:

```
<nvd3-bar-chart></nvd3-bar-chart>
```

Directive

```
angular.module('app.graphs')
    .directive('nvd3BarChart',
        function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                template: '<nvd3 options="nvd3_options" data="bar_data" api="api"></nvd3>',
                link: function(scope) {
                    scope.nvd3_options = {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'discreteBarChart',....
```

The bar_data property is set in the controller and the chart works fine. However I want to reuse the directive to bind to different data properties in the controller.

Something like this. Essentially linking the data attribute on the custom directive to the template inside the directive

```
//Temperature data would be set in controller
<nvd3-bar-chart data="temperature_data"></nvd3-bar-chart>

//Precipitation data would be set in controller
<nvd3-bar-chart data="precipitation_data"></nvd3-bar-chart>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this using by specifying the attribute directly on the custom directive

When angular replaces the directive markup with the template markup, it adds any attributes to the replaced html line.

Answer (score 1):

```
scope: {
 dataParam: '@'
},
template: '<nvd3 options="nvd3_options" data="{{dataParam}}" api="api"></nvd3>',
```

without isolate scope:

```
template: '<nvd3 options="nvd3_options" data="{{dataParam}}" api="api"></nvd3>',
link: function (scope, element, attr) {
    scope.dataParam = attr.dataParam;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when I tried it, it gave me the error =Multiple directives [nvd3BarChart (module: app.graphs), nvd3] asking for new/isolated scope

Comment: However if I set the markup to be <nvd3-bar-chart data="temperature_data"></nvd3-bar-chart> without setting the data attribute in the template, it works perfectly. 

But setting a new scope and replacing based on a parameter doesn't work

Comment: sorry didn't work Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression

though I did make it work by skipping the data attribute in the template of the directive and using it while using the directive. Angular seems to merge the attributes while rendering the dom so my usecase works :)